# Running a web application without internet on ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, dns, apache-http-server, hotspot

I have a web application running on Apache server which responds to the mobile client requests over the internet. My plan is to implement this in to an offline Linux pc which does not have any internet connection available.
[image: Offline implementation]

I need to have a local offline network which will have the application server and the client devices on it like in the above image. I tried following steps.

- Implement a hotspot network which will enable the mobile devices to connect to the application.
- Configure DNS on the same Linux pc to direct the client requests.
- Direct all client requests to a [docker](https://www.docker.com/) that have the web application in it.

I configured the DNS according to the steps mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/331568). I was trying to have the hotspot using `hostapd` like [here](https://seravo.fi/2014/create-wireless-access-point-hostapd) but confused with having the above mentioned DNS configuration with it.

So my questions are,

1. Whether it is possible to attain my goal in this way? If not what are the possibilities to do this?
2. If possible what are the correct steps to configure hotspot with the DNS configuration?
3. How to enable the docker Apache service to the host pc?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `dhcpd` to give clients a default DNS server through DHCP, or manually. The guide you're using to configure hostapd uses dnsmasq as a DHCP server, however you're not using dnsmasq, you're using BIND9 (which just does DNS), thus the need for a separate DHCP server.

Install `dhcpd`, and use the following `/etc/dhcpd.conf` as a template:

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option routers YOUR_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS;
option domain-name-servers YOUR_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS, YOUR_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS;

subnet FIRST_THREE_OCTETS_OF_YOUR_SUBNET.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
pool {
max-lease-time 600;
range FIRST_THREE_OCTETS_OF_YOUR_SUBNET.10 FIRST_THREE_OCTETS_OF_YOUR_SUBNET.50;
option routers YOUR_IP_ADDRESS;
option domain-name-servers YOUR_IP_ADDRESS, YOUR_IP_ADDRESS;
allow unknown-clients;
}
}
```

If you're following your linked guide, `YOUR_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS` should be 192.168.8.1, and `FIRST_THREE_OCTETS_OF_YOUR_SUBNET` should be `192.168.8` - which means a line like `FIRST_THREE_OCTETS_OF_YOUR_SUBNET.0` should be written as `192.168.8.0`.

Consult the documentation for docker/your container to figure out how to open port 80 on your host, and you're away!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new to this. I don't need to use a physical router. Instead a hotspot at the pc. I'm configuring the DNS on the same pc. So what would be the IP address for `routers`? I need to have a static IP for the application server and dynamic IPs to the client mobile devices.

Comment: @Chamath the IP address of your server, which should be `192.168.8.1` if you're following your guide to the letter.

Comment: The [reference](https://seravo.fi/2014/create-wireless-access-point-hostapd) I was trying seems not working. Thought i restart the pc the hotspot is not available. Do you have any working steps for this...? Instead I tried [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/105217/how-do-i-create-a-non-adhoc-wifi-hotspot) which works but I was unable to combine with the DNS. Do you have any idea about the situation?

Comment: @Chamath ignore the stuff about dnsmasq there, and follow the dhcpd guidelines in my answer. except for that guide, YOUR_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS is `192.168.3.1` and FIRST_THREE_OCTETS_OF_YOUR_SUBNET is `192.168.3`.

Comment: Ok. now i need to use "api.test.com" instead of `YOUR_SERVER_IP_ADDRESS` when accessing the server. How can I have this DNS mapping in this network implementation? Similar thing has discussed over [here](http://superuser.com/questions/591924/how-to-change-dns-on-hotspot). But how to do this?